# Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBox v/s System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Consider following 2 cases:

Case 1 --> **System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList**

I have two dropdownlists. I assign 1 to other as

```
ddl1 = ddl2
```

Then I perform

```
ddl2.items.clear().
```

This will reset the data for ddl1 also (correct me if wrong).

Case 2 --> **Telerik.WebControls.RadComboBox**

same steps as above

```
radcb1 = radcb2
radcb2.items.clear()
```

will this also clear the data from radcb1??

Comment: Have you tried it? radcb1 and radcb2 are just two references pointing to the same RadComboBox instance. So you are clearing the items of that instance (the one radcb2 initially pointed to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the statement `radcb1 = radcb2` you have two variables referencing (pointing to) the same `RadComboBox` instance (the one `radcb2` initially pointed to).

So the following line `radcb2.Items.Clear()` will only clear the items of that instance.

As for your first example: this works the same, i.e. your assumption that this will also clear the items of `ddl1` is wrong.

Comment: for case 1 i have tried and it surely clears 'ddl1' also.